# python modules: share variables and enable running files

Tags: python, package

sorry for this newbie question.

I've got a `client.py` and `server.py` scripts, which I want to use to write a simple socket game. I would like to build a python package out of it. I would like the default host and port to be defined in a central place of the package. Should it be `__init__.py`? I would like the scripts to be run from the command line. It can be either:

```
$ ./server.py
$ ./client.py
```

or

```
$ ./run.py server
$ ./run.py client
```

There would be one additional file, e.g. game.py which would hold the game logic. I'm a bit confused about how to organise files into a package in this situation...

Comment: __init__.py is to declare and load python module in that directory, for configuration, you can use ini in Windows, plist in Mac or JSON such file format, Python have standard library to support those file format. For single script file or two, it depends on how many code  are common for server.py and client.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can create package for game itself and create bin script which will run either client or server. I think such data as default host and port could be stored in settings module `settings.py` or `config.py` which will be imported in both `client.py` and `server.py`

Comment: thanks, but how can I organize my files to run client or server in one of the above ways? I mean - how could a `run.py` file look like to make it work?